# Python match and return string in between

Tags: python, regex

I have following code

```
stringA = "xxxxxxFoundAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaFoundBxxxxxxx"
stringB = "FoundA"
stringC = "FoundB"
```

How do I do a regular expression in python in order to return `aaaaaaaaaaaaaa`?

Comment: what happens if you have `stringA = "xxxxxxFoundAaaaaaFoundAaaaaFoundBaaaaaFoundBxxxxxxx"` ???

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
>>>
>>> stringA = "xxxxxxFoundAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaFoundBxxxxxxx"
>>> stringB = "FoundA"
>>> stringC = "FoundB"
>>>
>>> import re
>>> re.search(re.escape(stringB)+"(.*?)"+re.escape(stringC),stringA).group(1)
'aaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
>>>
```

Comment: **FAIL** didn't use re.escape() **

Answer (score 4):

```
re.search(re.escape(stringB) + "(.*?)" + re.escape(stringC), stringA).group(1)
```